# USSD session timeout (udp PROMPT)

Tags: ussd

I want to develop a ussd application that waits for user input (PROMPT). I was wondering how to handle a case, when for example ussd message is sent at night and user replies after several hours. For sure any timeout cannot handle it. On my phone (sony xperia) the message with the question is still displayed and i can reply seeing no error. But server side, I do not receive this reply because ussd session expired.

Resending the message several times is not a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do it!

You want to develop an application(server side) that accept input from mobile handset(client side)

I didn't understand well if your application is:

- Mobile-initiated (USSD/ PULL)
- Network-initiated (USSD/ PUSH)

but however in both cases you cannot achieve your goal.

Because session timeout is server side and there is nothing client could do about it, beside to resend the request which is not an option in your case.